# Im in absolute must recover text msgs in my storage

Tags: android

Im not sure if im in the right place to ask this of you experts. I am not a computer person and very unaware of the dynamics of them..im in absolute desperate need to retrieve all text msgs from one number beginning 7.23.18.  Ive tried to do everything i possibly could do and might have fsctory reset all info.  But i did find some thing in .../storage/emulated/0/android/data/com.google.android.apps.messaging......and..../files... Is this some of them....i dont know and if they are part....i have no idea how to retrieve them to be readable...i keep trying..for weeks...if one of you experts can share your intellectual knowledge...i will even pay for it to get all these...i have to have them...im being stalked and this is is only way i can put him away for life.....before he comes back....thank you more than you know....just fir giving me your time to read my request...i guess ill just wait to see what happens...Debbie. Ventura Beach,  Ca.

Comment: I suggest you contact the police. They can do it if necessary. Also, if you are willing to pay I'm sure you can find a lab near where you live that can do that.

Comment: Thanks,  A lab..?? For my android phone..??  Ok..ill try...you mean a forensics type lab..probably...the one i wirk in is SmithKline Clinical Labs, Beckman...and we do biology, hematology and that sort of stuff.  The Police have their report they need from me (which they were aware of actions before) and the District Prosecutor Attorney are the ones who told me to get all my texts for a stronger court case to end this, totally.......ANYWAY..... I REALLY APPRECIATE YOU JUST CONTACTING ME BACK WITH A LITTLE HOPE STILL...THANK YOU...Debbie...

Answer (score 1):

Reach out to your wireless provider.

T-Mobile has all my texts going back years.